# Jacobi elliptic function JacobiSN[z,1/2] should be equal to JacobiSN[z , -1/2], But MATHEMATICA shows different values, Why?

Tags: special-functions

Jacobi elliptic function JacobiSN[z,1/2] should be equal to JacobiSN[z , -1/2] by their properties(NIST Handbook of Mathematical functions, SN[z,k]=SN[z,-k]). But in MATHEMATICA they are giving different values, Why is this happening? Graph of JacobiSN[z,1/2] - JacobiSN[z , -1/2] is show here, which should be actually zero. Can any one explain this? [image: Graph of JacobiSN[z,1/2] - JacobiSN[z , -1/2] as obtained in MATHEMATICA]

Comment: *Mathematica* uses the **parameter** convention, while the DLMF uses the **modulus** convention. See [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EllipticIntegralsAndEllipticFunctions.html) and [this](https://dlmf.nist.gov/22.1) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/108659). (Note for comparison that [Abramowitz and Stegun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_569.htm) uses the same convention as *Mathematica*.)

Comment: Both conventions are Ok, but  the equation JacobiSN[ z , m] = JacobiSN[ z , -m] should hold as a standard definition of extension to negative parameters. In MATHEMATICA they are not equal for any 0<m<1, for eg., m=1/2

Comment: Again: `JacobiSN[z, m] == JacobiSN[z, -m]` is ***not*** identically true in *Mathematica*, because it is using the parameter convention. If you really want to use the modulus, then the definition you want is `mySN[z_, k_] := JacobiSN[z, k^2]`, and in that case, `mySN[z, k] == mySN[z, -k]` is indeed true.

Comment: That is OK, thank you